# Batch file hold shift key to hightlight

Tags: vba, windows, batch-file, cmd, sendkeys

we run WinSQL with DB2's begin and end statements.  We have multiple scripts in one file.  I was wondering if there was a way to hold down shift with SendKeys to use the right arrow/down arrows to highlight the text I want to run.  Does it need a loop?  And how do I do a 5 second delay before it starts so I can switch the windows when I run it?  I tried:

```
set /P "=Wait and send a command: " < NUL
ping -n 1 -w 1 127.0.0.1 > NUL
%SendKeys% "^{RIGHT}"
```

for the highlighting, multiple times, but it forgets about the shift key and just moves right multiple times.

Thanks

Comment: Batch files do not have a send keys method.  That is only available in VB and Jscript.

Comment: Yes, I use JScript in the batch file with:
    
    rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
    set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

    var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));

Comment: Convert your batch file to vbs and for the *Shift* key, refer to [SendKeys statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement) from MS Docs.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, I just don't know hot to hold shift down while continually holding pressing the arrow key so I can highlight strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your sendkeys.

Example

```
%SendKeys% "+{right}"
```

^ is for CTRL key rather than shift.

Then for delay try cmd command `timeout /t 5`

On another note since you're using vbs also, you can use that to switch your windows as well.

```
Dim ObjShell :Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ObjShell.AppActivate("Notepad")
```

Comment: Yeah a typo by me, I use ^c and ^v even and didn't even notice that!  Thanks for your help!